# Swift 5 self.displayAlert error - "Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'displayAlert'"

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to make a sign in and sign out function using back4app. There is an error with the `self.displayAlert` lines, with xcode saying

> Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'displayAlert'

Code:

```
@IBAction func signin(_ sender: Any) {
    PFUser.logInWithUsername(inBackground: self.userSignin.text!, password: self.passSignin.text!) {
      (user: PFUser?, error: Error?) -> Void in
      if user != nil {
        self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Login Successful", message: "")
      } else {
        self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error!.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
}

@IBAction func signup(_ sender: Any) {
    let user = PFUser()
    user.username   = self.userSignup.text
    user.password = self.passsSignup.text
    
    user.signUpInBackground {(succeeded: Bool, error: Error?) -> Void in
        if let error = error{
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            self.displayAlert(withTitle: "Success", message: "Account has been successfully created")
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: [Displaying Alerts with UIAlertController in Swift](https://www.appypie.com/uialertcontroller-alerts-swift-how-to)

Comment: Are you missing a method in your view controller called `func displayAlert()`? The error seems to suggest it's missing. Have a look at [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller) for how to present alerts from a `UIViewController` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

add this extension :

```
    extension UIViewController {
        
        func displayAlert(withTitle: String, message: String) {
            
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title:withTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
               
            }
            alertController.addAction(action1)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } 
}
```